# Can't resize tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm very new to TeX and can't seem to figure out why this table isn't resizing.

I've tried several different solutions from other threads online but nothing seems to be working nicely.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\doublerulesep{0.5pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ || l | l | l || }
        \hhline{|==|}
        \textbf{What will be measured} & \textbf{Why is it being measured} 
        & \textbf{How is it being measured}\\
            \hhline{|==|}

        High fps camera footage. & Have a visual record of the secondary 
        mission events. & Using the bridgetek CleO-CAM1 camera module.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        Barometric pressure, temperature, humidity and environmental gasses. & 
        For telemetry to base station, fulfilling primary mission. & Via a 
        PCB-integrated Bosch BME680.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        Vrms across secondary mission inductor coils. & For power calculations
        and analysis from base station. & A non-inverting amplifier used 
        to proportionally increase voltage output. A high resolution 
        linear ADC reads voltage.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        GPS coordinates. & To aid cansat tracking. & The MTK3339 GPS 
        is mounted to the main PCB and wired to a dedicated antenna 
        on the side of the cansat.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        Rotation, acceleration and relative position. & Additional data to aid
        primary and secondary mission. & FXOS8700 + FXAS21002 9DOF
        module soldered to the main PCB.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        Vibrations. & Data for secondary mission power generation 
        performance. & Mechanical vibration sensor with accelerometer 
        from 9DOF package.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        3D magnetic field strength. & Data for secondary mission efficiency
        analysis. & 3 Honeywell SS400 Series hall effect sensors aligned 
        to 3 independent axes.\\
        \hhline{|--|}
        Rms current generated by secondary mission inductor coils. & For 
        power calculations and analysis from base station. & ACS712ELC in
        series with each inductor coil.\\
        \hhline{|==|}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

This gives me the following output, which does not fit horizontally onto an A4 portrait page:

[image: Output Table]

Comment: Within `tabularx` the column specifiers which should get sized automatically to match the declared width are `X` not `l`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please keep in mind to add a small **compilable** document called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in future. You could always edit your question and add something. Nevertheless `X` instead `l` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't allow automatic line-breaking. Since you're using a `tabularx` environment, you really should use the `X` column type instead of the `l` column type, for all three columns.

I would further like to encourage you to give the table a much more "open" material, by (a) omitting all vertical lines, (b) using far fewer horizontal lines, and (c) using the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw the remaining few horizontal lines. No more `\hline` and `\hhline` directives... Note that whitespace can be every bit as effective as black lines for creating visual separation.

Your readers will appreciate the table's open look -- and they will likely reward your effort by actually taking the time to read and assimilate the table's contents. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page block parameters suitably

\begin{document}
% just for this example...
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{1}
\subsubsection{What will be measured, why, and how?}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % default value: 6pt
%% \centering % not needed since "tabularx" occupies full width of text block
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYY @{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{What will be measured} & 
        \textbf{Why is it being measured} & 
        \textbf{How is it being measured}\\
        \midrule

        High fps camera footage. 
        & Have a visual record of the secondary mission events. 
        & Using the bridgetek CleO-CAM1 camera module.\\

        \addlinespace
        Barometric pressure, temperature, humidity and environmental gasses. 
        & For telemetry to base station, fulfilling primary mission. 
        & Via a PCB-integrated Bosch BME680.\\

        \addlinespace
        Vrms across secondary mission inductor coils. 
        & For power calculations and analysis from base station. 
        & A non-inverting amplifier used to proportionally increase voltage output. A high resolution linear ADC reads voltage.\\

        \addlinespace
        GPS coordinates. 
        & To aid cansat tracking. 
        & The MTK3339 GPS is mounted to the main PCB and wired to a dedicated antenna on the side of the cansat.\\

        \addlinespace
        Rotation, acceleration and relative position. 
        & Additional data to aid primary and secondary mission. 
        & FXOS8700 + FXAS21002 9DOF module soldered to the main PCB.\\

        \addlinespace
        Vibrations. 
        & Data for secondary mission power generation performance. 
        & Mechanical vibration sensor with accelerometer from 9DOF package.\\

        \addlinespace
        3D magnetic field strength. 
        & Data for secondary mission efficiency analysis. 
        & 3 Honeywell SS400 Series hall effect sensors aligned to 3 independent axes.\\

        \addlinespace
        Rms current generated by secondary mission inductor coils. 
        & For power calculations and analysis from base station. 
        & ACS712ELC in series with each inductor coil. \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice explanation ... (+1)